# Rabbit's favorite beverage

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Your best friend, the rabbit, was coming out of his burrow one morning and you happened to be nearby!

"Good morning, friend!" said the rabbit.

"Good morning!"

"I've got a puzzle for you... Think you can get me something to drink?"

"Hmm... What do you mean?" you replied.

The rabbit merely chuckled and gave you a small scrap of paper. With that, he continued to burrow into the ground!

`EXEREDSEEND.HREENRRREVHS.TETTT.SEO.FUEHHHI......OEI`

What did the rabbit want to drink?

Hint 1:

> Since someone has already figured out the first part, I won't bother with hints about that. For the second part, a more general form of the numbers would be `6 4 1 3 3 7`, though that won't be exactly what the rabbit wanted to drink!

Comment: It always makes me happy when I'm online and see a new puzzle of yours pop up, they are always so clever and unexpected!

Comment: @Sciborg -- That's really nice of you! I'm glad you enjoy them and you just made my day!

Comment: You might not tell of course, but is there rot13(nalguvat va gur chmmyr juvpu vaqvpngrf jung gb qb NSGRE gur svefg fgrc? Ab vqrn jung bgure guvatf V pna qb jvgu gur qrpelcgrq grkg)

Comment: @LukasRotter -- Good question! Once you've gotten the first step, the clues for the next step are just what you decoded. You should post a partial answer if you've gotten the first step, though!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rabbit wants

> Coffee (Dewey decimal 641.3373) as solved by LR

Comment: Oh, _that's_ what he wanted? Hmm... Thanks for letting me know, but I'm not sure I'll be giving him any! Good job, this is correct!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I'm assuming he got the coffee from Dunkin' Donuts

Comment: @ferret -- Haha, maybe! The DD was to clue the Dewey Decimal system, though.

Answer (score 12):

<sub>[Partial] Ok I give up, somebody else solve this please, soon I will be AFK for one hour :)</sub>

---

First step:

> Decrypt the given ciphertext using the [Burrows-Wheeler transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform), clued by the word burrow. Result: 
>  `DD.SIX.FOUR.ONE.THREE.THREE.SEVEN.THREEHERE.IS.THE`
>  which spells `Here is the DD 6 4 1 3 3 7 3`
>  Now figure out what DD means, I guess?
>  Here's what I've already tried with the number 6413373:
>  - A1Z26, A0Z25
>  - Dec -> Hex, Oct -> Hex
>  - Cryptogram
>  - (rab)bits don't produce alphanumeric characters when interpreted as ASCII
>  - Maybe an ID of some sort? Definitely not of a question on this site, way too large.

Comment: Great start! Yes, you have to figure out what DD means!

Comment: Added a hint in case you wanna take a stab at the next part!